# Cannot use input field after using a reset function in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm struggling with a simple task in React
I have an input field that accepts a string or number.
When pressing the reset button, the value of the input field should go blank so I can add a new string.
I've made it possible to clear the form but when it's cleared, I can't type something else.
Is it because I'm using state?
Any solutions?

my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Input.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

const Input = () => {

    const [value, setValue] = useState();

    const SearchButton = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("click");
    };

    const ResetButton = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setValue(" ");

    };

    return (
        <main>
        <form className='inputfield'>
            <h2 className='input-text'>Zoek een Github user</h2>
            <div className='input'>
            <input className='search' type='text' placeholder='Typ hier een gebruikersnaam...' value={value}></input>
                <div className='button-field'>
                    <button className='search-now' onClick={SearchButton}>Zoeken</button>
                    <button className='reset' onClick={ResetButton}>Reset</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        </main>
    );
};

export default Input;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have an `onChange` function in your inputs.

```html
<input onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}></input>
```

[Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)

Comment: It says that 'value' is assaigned a value but never used...

Comment: Yes, you still need to keep your original code. You just need to add in the onChange function to the input element.

Comment: Nevermind, David showed me how to do it. However, your solution worked

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to update state when changing the value.  For example:

```
<input
  className='search'
  type='text'
  placeholder='Typ hier een gebruikersnaam...'
  value={value}
  onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
></input>
```

Basically what's happening is that when your component first loads you *aren't* using state, so the `input` is "uncontrolled" because `value` is `undefined`.  Then the "reset" sets a value to the state, so the `input` now uses that value.  But it needs a way to *change* that value.

As an aside, I also recommend using an empty string as the initial state, instead of `undefined`:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("");
```

That way the value is at least *something*, even if it's empty.  You might also want the "reset" to use an empty string instead of a space:

```
setValue("");
```

Because a space is a non-empty value, and it causes the placeholder text to no longer show.  So it isn't really "resetting" the input, it's just changing it to a whitespace value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to change the `setValue` value and it should look like this

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('');
```

and secondly you need to add this to the input

```
<input onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}></input>
```

Comment: please use English in your answer many users can't Spanish.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).